# Enum Flags values reset on function call, UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-input, enum-flags

I'm trying to implement a simple switch between the control of 2 gameobjects in unity. Said switch can only happen when the entity you're switching from is grounded.

[Base Flags values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qivtW.png)

The issue is that the gameobject's flags apparently get reset to their default values whenever I press the switch key, and because the object's spawning position is airborne, the switch can never happen.

[Game launched in editor values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNZUc.png)

[InputSwitch Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcDXr.png)

[Values at the time of the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0nrg.png)

I'm completely lost as to why the flags get reset, nothing in my code tells me that it would do that, and even after trying to print some values at different points of the process, everything seems to be in order until the switch function gets called, and said function doesn't call upon all these other values at all excepy for a check on the Grounded flag.

Anyone knows what could be happening?

Comment: they dont look reset, it looks like it decided your player isnt airborne and is now grounded..... nothing more or less.

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue o mapping the object instead of the prefab to the component. bug dumb. fixed now.